# Is my propane company lying to me?

Tags: leak, propane

I had my propane company come to install a Tankless water heater & dryer. They changed the regulator at the tanks but didn't get a perfect flare so that junction had a very small leak. 2 months later I noticed that I had used 70% of my propane.  I complained to the supplier and was told that only Vapor was leaking and that it would not account for the fuel loss. This sounds like pure BS to me.  Is there any reason that I should believe them????

The other factors involved are: This is a summer rental home so the home was vacant for the 2 months in question.
The propane furnace is only used for emergency heat  when the heat pump can't keep up.  The first cold snap we had the temperature dropped to 35 on the first floor.
My HVAC guy checked it out and found that my furnace was dead and not capable of burning any propane.

Comment: No such thing as a "very small" gas leak.  Can you post a historical weather chart from mid-December to late Feb? We don't care where you live, but parts of the country had an appalling winter.

Comment: I'm not sure who you'd call, but I'd start with the Better Business Bureau (BBB).  Then I'd call the local building department, and ask them who else I could file a complaint with.   There's no way your supplier should leave you with a leak.

Comment: " and was told that only Vapor was leaking and that it would not account for the fuel loss"   They must think their customers  are morons.  Liquid Propane turns to a vapor gas when it leaves its tank so it can be burned. File a complaint with the regulatory body in your area.

Comment: "Only vapor" in the leak means that somewhere inside the tank, "only liquid" is turning into "only vapor".

Comment: To clarify - They did fix the leak but old me that I didn't loose any propane because only the Vapor was leaking. When I explained that I wasn't 'uninformed' they had a manager get back to me. He explained that a small leak over 2 months wouldn't amount to much.

Answer (score 3):

Call the firefighters telling them that you smell gas, then if there are issues. If FF will find an issue, you'll have the right to ask your company for a fix.

Anyway: gas is a bad beast, so call FF just for your own safety.